# Strange behaviour of findall

Tags: python-3.x, findall, python-re

```
import re
text1 = '"Python", "PHP", "Java",'
print(re.findall(r'P(.*?)n', text1))
```

Expected output : ['Python']

Actual output : ['ytho']

Though the regex engine matches with 'Python', findall ignores 'P' and 'n' in output. Can someone tell what is actually happening here

Comment: Using enclosed parenthesis denotes a capturing group. The regex is correctly finding "Python" based on the regex, and returning the results from the capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

You need a non-capturing group:

```
re.findall(r'P(?:.*?)n', text1)
```

Note the `?:` after the opening parenthesis. Otherwise, `re` captures only the part of the string that matches the expression in the parentheses.